# Selling Products of one Magento store to other Magento website via Api?

Tags: php, magento

How can i sale products from my Magento store to some other Magento website(having different databse,domain). Using SOAP API or any other way.

Comment: you will get better help from this website http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Magento has soap server which you can configure in your "Magento Admin" to work with any soap client.
2. Magento don't have soap client build in it to communicate to another magento as a server.
3. For you to achieve your aim, you have to build custom module for magento.
4. Setting up a SOAP account:     First of all you need a special
   proxy-user for SOAP. Within your application you will  build a
   SOAP-client and this client will act a bit the same as a regular
   browser. It will request a certain "page" within the Magento
   application, but because this page is only accessible if you have
   the proper permissions, you need to create an user account.

   Before we create the actual user we will need to create a role for
   this user first. Login on the Admin Panel as administrator and
   browse to System, then Webservices and then SOAP/XML_RPC Roles. Create a new role
   and select the Resources this role gives access to.

   In this example we will add a role "API Full Access" that has full
   access to all of the resources. In real life you should make a
   thorough study of which role with which permissions is sufficient
   for your goal. Adding an API user that can access and modify all
   resources opens up for a little of extra security risks.

   After creating the role, we need to create an API user. Browse to
   System, then Webservices and then SOAP/XML-RPC Roles. The new user needs of
   course an username and also an API key (which can seen as a
   password). Make note of this username and API key, because these are
   the details we need to configure in our SOAP client. We will assume
   the username "soaper" here. Before saving the new user, make sure
   the proper User Role is selected ("API Full Acccess").
5. Creating SOAP Client:

   ```
   client = new SoapClient('http://mymagentohost/api/soap?wsdl');
   ```

   // If somestuff requires api authentification,
   // then get a session token
   $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

   $result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method');
   $result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method', 'arg1');
   $result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method', array('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'));
   $result = $client->multiCall($session, array(
        array('somestuff.method'),
        array('somestuff.method', 'arg1'),
        array('somestuff.method', array('arg1', 'arg2'))
   ));

   // If you don't need the session anymore
   $client->endSession($session);

   To read more on how to create soap client, try this link
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html !

Comment: thanks for reply i have done with all five steps you mentioned . But the thing is can i display products from database of Magento site (server) to Magento site B(client) exactly as in server via API.I m using following code to just listing all products.

Comment: yes, u can use to display all kind of product and categories and as well depend on the access u gave to the user role of that user.

Comment: Check this link for all method and argument u can pass along. http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html